# Android Layout/View Rotation/Positioning

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I have a RelativeLayout with an ImageView and 8 TextView's in it. I want to position labels around this image dynamically. I thought the best approach would be to rotate the image at 45 degree intervals and place a label at each position, however the Image/RelativeLayout doesn't redraw (even if invalidate is called) until the next predetermind onDraw call, and all the TextViews get put in the message queue for positioning after that, so all the TextViews get positioned ontop of each other at the 315 degree mark.

I tried posting a Runnable to the RelativeLayout in a hope it would be added to the message queue after the onDraw call but unfortunately it didn't work and I'm running out of ideas.

My current code is bellow to give an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
public void setupMenuText() {
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    setupMenuItemText((TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_text_pos0), (72*scale)+0.5f);
    setupMenuItemText((TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_text_pos1), (72*scale)+0.5f);
    setupMenuItemText((TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_text_pos2), (72*scale)+0.5f);
    setupMenuItemText((TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_text_pos3), (72*scale)+0.5f);
    setupMenuItemText((TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_text_pos4), (72*scale)+0.5f);
    setupMenuItemText((TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_text_pos5), (72*scale)+0.5f);
    setupMenuItemText((TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_text_pos6), (72*scale)+0.5f);
    setupMenuItemText((TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_text_pos7), (72*scale)+0.5f);
}

public void setupMenuItemText(TextView pT, float pY) {
    relativeLayout.setRotation(relativeLayout.getRotation()+45);
    pT.setText("Some Text");
    pT.setRotation(0);
    pT.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    pT.setX(0);
    pT.setY(pY);
}
```

**EDIT: Thanks to JSchools for the answer, wasn't exactly what I needed but pointed me in the right direction and info was accurate.**

**For anyone else with the same problem, centering the text inside the TextView wont cut it. I manually had to set the size of the TextView to much higher than its intended use so that it would accurately be positioned relative to the image.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the rotation of each individual TextView. You seem to be rotating the container multiple times, but since all the TextViews are inside the container, and they all have zero rotation relative to the container, they seem stacked. Don't rotate the container at all. You will also need to set the position of the TextViews so that they will be arranged in a circle. Simply rotating them will stick them on top of each other.